# How can I limit the number of class attendees in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I offer multiple workshops with different prices and availability limits, such as follows:

```
A Class - $10 - 2 participants max
B Class - $15 - 1 participant max
```

If John signs up for both Class A and B for $25 total, how can I ensure that Doe is only able to sign up for Class A since Class B is full?

Answer (score 2):

You can limit selections in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) by assigning [quantity limits](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/quantity-limits) to your choice fields.  Simply do the following:

1. Select **Limit Quantities** under *Choice Options*
2. Enter quantities for each choice, or leave blank for unlimited
3. Set the **Quantity Exceeded Error Message** to *Class is full!*

You can learn more about quantity limits in our [help documentation](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/18/building-forms/limiting-quantities)!

[image: limit quantities for choice field in Cognito Forms]